# Hover effect not working properly on multiselect

Tags: css, hover

I'm using this [library](http://loudev.com/#demos). 
for an example see the first DEMO (Pre-selected options). the `hover` effect not working properly in the **selected** side.(some times the `li` tag change the color but sometimes doesn't )

Can someone familiar with this please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: I'm just referring to that site's DEMO. I saw it has a problem. Just ask whether someone in SO know a solution. someone who used it maybe.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by 'hover effect not working properly'? It seems to be working okay for me (I'm using FF 29.0.1).

Comment: i got the issue like this. try adding few and then wait a bit and add another few. then try to check the hover effect. It will not work on the newly selected ones.

Comment: @thePav : I did some changes to the CSS file like in the answer. BTW I don't know it is the correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve that. Don't know it is okay or not. but it worked.

in the CSS file I removed the below code.

```
/*.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-hover,
  .ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #08c;
}*/
```

and added a new code to do it just for **li** tags.

```
li:hover{
cursor: pointer !important;
color: #fff !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
background-color: #08c !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Javascript to apply styles (changing classes when mouse is hover). ¿Why no use CSS directly? Simply one change: selector *.ms-hover* to *:hover*.

```
.ms-container .ms-selectable li:hover,
.ms-container .ms-selection li:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #08c;
}
```